# How to disable the Drop down list in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having two drop down list C1 and D1 where C1 contains Country list.
D1 should act like a drop down only when UAE and VN selected in C1 list

If I select the country other than UAE and VN the D1 act as a normal cell instead of Drop down.

I am unable to disable the Drop down when I select country other countries than UAE and VN, D1 still act as Drop down list

```
Sub excelCode()

Dim myValue As Variant


  myValue = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value

  If myValue = "UAE" Or myValue = "VN" Then

  ActiveSheet.DropDowns("D1").Enabled = True

    Else

     ActiveSheet.DropDowns("D1").Enabled = False

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: how/where do you run this code?

Comment: Where are `a` and `dd` used?

Comment: I run this code on Visual basic application

Comment: a and dd are no more there sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Do you have a reason for not using data validation?

Comment: If no, you may want to look into cascading/dependent dropdown menus

Comment: @Rory Is it possible without using vba script? as I gone through some articles they suggested me to use the VBA

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I did the cascading drop down only, now i need to disable that drop down list on selection of other drop down like i mentioned in a question above

Comment: Yes, you just just a formula that doesn't return a valid range if the cell doesn't contain either of those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below will `only work on ActiveX List Boxes`. Since your description uses "US" and "UAE" values and your code uses "UAE" an "VN" values, I elected to use your code values, you can change to meet your needs. `Place the code in your worksheet module`, change the sheet number as needed. `ListBox2 will only be enabled` when either of the two values are selected; if any other value is selected, then `ListBox2 will be disabled`.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
'You must use ActiveX Control List Box
    With Sheet1.ListBox1
            If .Value = "UAE" Or .Value = "VN" Then
                Sheet1.ListBox2.Enabled = True

            Else: Sheet1.ListBox2.Enabled = False

            End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I need to use the List not list box in my code